# Django-registration Module success_url is not returning

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am customizing the django-registration module. So far I am passing the url like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls

from profile import UserRegistrationForm
from registration.views import register
import regbackend, views
from accounts import profile
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
  #  (r'^conf/admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','success_url':profile,'form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
    (r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)),
    url('^profile/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'profile.html'}, name="profile"),


)
```

When the url is requested I get the error `No module named django.views` and it is not going to the `success_url`.

I think i am doing something wrong in `urls.py` but I can't see what. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please could you update your post to include your full urls.py?

Comment: Also some kind of stacktrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','success_url':profile,'form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
```

To this:

```
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(
        form_class=UserRegistrationForm,
        success_url='profile/',),
    name='registration_register',
    ),
```

I've not used a named URL here, but it can be easier to get it working at all with a hardcoded URL and change it to named when you're sure everything else works.